# Did the Japanese use native Camellia species before Camellia sinensis was introduced from China?

Tags: japan, food, classical-japan

According to Wikipedia the first known references to tea occured in the 9th century, when Buddhist monks introduced [tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_tea_in_Japan), a drink made from *Camellia sinensis* to Japan.

The *Camellia* variety *sinensis* is not native to Japan, (or not considered so, anyways,) but there are actually other *Camellia* species that are native to Japan, such as [*japonica*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_japonica) and [*sasanqua*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sasanqua), and they can be used to make a similar tea beverage. *Japonica* is pretty much in the name, *sasanqua* is native to China and Japan.

I wonder why there seems to be no apparent evidence that these other plants were used before *Camellia sinensis*.

Also, something about the ancient writing systems of Jindai Moji—in reference to what is little known about ancient Japan, even though many believe the entireity of these these writing systems are more recent forgeries.

Comment: Do you have a source that mentions *japonica* and *sasanqua* as being native to Japan? And what exactly is the relevance of "something about the ancient writing systems of Jindai Moji"?

Comment: Japonica is pretty much in the name, sasanqua is native to China and Japan. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_sasanqua https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_japonica Jindai Moji is in reference to what is little known about ancient Japan, even though many believe the entireity of these these writing systems are more recent forgeries.

Comment: I edited your comment into the question, but it sounds like it should stand alone. Do you mean it as a Q&A on what is presently made of the Jindai Moji or is it linked to tea in some way?

Comment: It's not really linked to tea, it's just (maybe) related to ancient Japan in general.